# Is there a dataset of temperatures in India before 1947?

Tags: data-request, weather, geospatial, india

I am trying to get a dataset of temperatures in India before 1947 - say 100 odd years (before partition). Is there a web-site or some place where I could visualize such data or even have graphs of temperature of that period ?

It would be preferable if such information is either in .csv or .json format (both are foss formats) making it easier to manipulate and get some patterns out of it.

Comment: @JanDoggen thank you for the pointer, have done it, hope the above is a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to obtain such old datasets.

Depending what you are trying to do you could use the 20th century reanlysis made by NOAA-CIRES. The description of the dataset:

- https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/20thC_Rean/#plot

It is a modeled dataset and you can extract several variables as surface temperature on a latitude, longitude position.

Other option is the post-processed dataset released by the CRU: Read the ReadMe:

- https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/cru_ts_3.23/crucy.1506241137.v3.23/

Other modelled dataset is the 20th century reanalysis by the ECMWF:

- http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/cera20c/levtype=sfc/type=an/
- http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/era20c-daily/levtype=sfc/type=an/